# stop php adding new line

Tags: php, javascript, arrays, wordpress, newline

i am trying to add the posts from my word press blog to a javascript array however it keeps adding a new line and causing errors in the javascript. here is the code

```
  <?php $num = 0 ; require($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/blog/wp-load.php');query_posts('showposts=3');if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
    news_content[<?php echo $num; ?>]="<a href='<?php the_permalink(); ?>' title='<?php the_title(); ?>'><?php the_title(); ?></a>Posted on <?php the_time('l jS F, Y') ?><?php the_excerpt(); ?>";

  <?php $num = $num + 1; endwhile; else: echo "no posts"; endif; ?>
  <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

`the_excerpt();` keeps returning `<p>post</p>` and a new line, causing a error

How can i get rid of the new line?

Comment: Without posting `the_exceprt()` we can hardly help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest would be to modify the function `the_excerpt`.

If that's not possible:

```
ob_start();
the_excerpt();
$out = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
echo rtrim($out);
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is a `\n`, you can just do something like

```
str_replace("\n","",the_excerpt());
```

see: http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php
Keeping in mind it might be `\n` or `\r\n`, depending on your system.

<sub>can I just remark that the "everything on one line" php is really unreadable? It's really hard to maintain, let alone to read/debug for us. Why not some more specious layout?</sub>